# Combinations of Products as single count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I need to count combinations of products within transactions differently to other products and I'm struggling with how to do this within a single select statement from SQL 2008. This would then become a data set to manipulate in Reporting Services

raw data looks like this

```
txn, prod, units  
1,    a,    2  
1,    c,    1  
2,    a,    1  
2,    b,    1  
2,    c,    1  
3,    a,    2  
3,    b,    1  
4,    a,    3  
4,    c,    2
```

So a+b should = one if in same trans number, however a or b should equal one if not paired. So a=1 and b=1 but a+b=1, a+b+a=2, a+b+a+b=2 given the example data here is my desired result with an explanation of why

```
txn 1 is 3 units -- 2a + c  
txn 2 is 2 units -- (a+b) + c  
txn 3 is 2 units -- (a+b) + a  
txn 4 is 5 units -- 3a + 2c
```

My query is more complex than this and includes other aggregates so I would like to group by transaction which I can't do as I need to manipulate at a lower grain

Update Progress :

Possible solution, I've generated columns based on the products I'm measuring. This allows me to group on Txn as I am now aggregating that field. Unsure if there's a better way to do it as it does take a little while

```
CASE    WHEN    SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='a' then 1 else 0 end)-
                SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='b' then 1 else 0 end)=0 
        THEN    SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='a' then 1 else 0 end) 
        ELSE 0 END AS MixProd
, CASE  WHEN    SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='a' then 1 else 0 end)-
                SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='b' then 1 else 0 end)!=0 
        THEN    ABS(SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='a' then 1 else 0 end)-
                    SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='b' then 1 else 0 end)) 
        ELSE 0 END AS NotMixProd
```

I will then need to sort out the current unit aggregate to remove the extras but this certainly gives me a start

Update Progress 2 :

This failed to handle 0 correctly where a or b was 0 it would still give a value for mix because a-b was not zero. I reverted to an earlier draft that I lost and expanded as per below

```
, CASE          WHEN        SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='a' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 THEN 0 
                WHEN        SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='b' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 THEN 0
                WHEN        SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='a' then 1 else 0 end)-
                            SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='b' then 1 else 0 end)=0 
                THEN        SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='a' then 1 else 0 end) 
                ELSE        ABS(SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='a' then 1 else 0 end)-
                            SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='b' then 1 else 0 end))       
                END AS MixProd
        , CASE  WHEN        SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='a' then 1 else 0 end)-
                            SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='b' then 1 else 0 end)!=0 
                THEN        ABS(SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='a' then 1 else 0 end)-
                            SUM(CASE    WHEN Prod='b' then 1 else 0 end)) 
                ELSE 0      END AS NotMixProd
```

Comment: Unclear. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I would like to GROUP BY txn, but I need to count products differently according to what other products are in the same txn. I can't simply CASE WHEN prod IN ('a','b') then 0.5 else 1 end because they are only worth 0.5 when together and then only the two that are together

Comment: Idea is to get `total=SUM(units), sa=SUM(CASE  prod WHEN 'a' THEN units END, sb =...` and then substract the number of pairs `res =  total - CASE WHEN sa > sb THEN sb ELSE sa END`

Comment: Thanks Serg that's similar to where I've gone I think. I've generated columns based on product code. Will elaborate below, be great to see if there's a leaner way of doing it though

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: This should work in SQL Server 2008 (based on LAG solution from [here](https://sqlscope.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/lag-and-lead-for-sql-server-2008/)).

Here is the demo:  http://rextester.com/GNI23706

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    select txn, prod, units,
     row_number() over (partition by txn order by prod) rn,
    (row_number() over (partition by txn order by prod))/2 rndiv2,
    (row_number() over (partition by txn order by prod)+1)/2 rnplus1div2,
    count(*) over (partition by txn) partitioncount
    from test_data
)

select 
txn,
sum(case when prev_prod = 'a' and prod = 'b' and prev_units >= units then 0
         when prev_prod = 'a' and prod = 'b' and prev_units < units then units - prev_units
         else units
    end) units
from
(
    select 
    txn,
    prod,
    units,
    CASE WHEN rn%2=1 
         THEN MAX(CASE WHEN rn%2=0 THEN prod END) OVER (PARTITION BY txn,rndiv2) 
         ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN rn%2=1 THEN prod END) OVER (PARTITION BY txn,rnplus1div2)
    END AS prev_prod,
    CASE WHEN rn%2=1 
         THEN MAX(CASE WHEN rn%2=0 THEN units END) OVER (PARTITION BY txn,rndiv2) 
         ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN rn%2=1 THEN units END) OVER (PARTITION BY txn,rnplus1div2)
    END AS prev_units
    from cte
) temp
group by txn
```

For SQL Server 2012+, use LAG:

```
select 
txn,
sum(
case when prev_prod = 'a' and prod = 'b' and prev_units >= units then 0
     when prev_prod = 'a' and prod = 'b' and prev_units < units then units - prev_units
     else units
end) units
from
(
    select 
    txn,
    prod,
    units,
    lag(prod) over (partition by txn order by prod) prev_prod,
    lag(units) over (partition by txn order by prod) prev_units
    from test_data
) temp
group by txn
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided in the end that a temp table was the best way to go, because I couldn't group on a collation. So I eventually tweaked the code above as it was failing to pick up the spare items correctly

```
SUM(Units) AS OldUnits
SUM(Units) - 
    (CASE WHEN 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Prod='a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN 0 WHEN 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Prod='b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN 0 WHEN 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Prod='a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Prod='b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Prod='a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHEN 
(SUM(CASE WHEN Prod='a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Prod='b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) < 0 THEN 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Prod='a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ELSE 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Prod='b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END) AS NewUnits
```

This was stored in a temptable that I could then collate on Trans as the next step. Works fine for my purposes and helped me overcome a mild irrational fear I have of temptables